Flat roof drainage / pooling
I am in the middle of a disagreement with some roofers about a flat roof, and I was wondering if anyone would provide an opinion? The main issue is the drainage. The flat roof is on a two storey bay window. It is a fairly large bay window. Along my street, all flat roofs of the same size have their own drainage systems (pipe to the side). The roofers installed an EDPM membrane which curves downwards towards the middle, so all the water fell off the flat roof to the front. This created quite a waterfall when there was heavy rain. I queried this and asked them to return to ensure that the drainage went to the side and into the downpipe. (NB this is what was specified in the agreed quotation). I specifically asked them to reprofile the roof so the fall goes to the side. They then returned, did nothing to the profile of the roof, but merely raised the lip (see picture). This means that if the water builds up enough, it will eventually drain to the side. However, this also means that the water will pool in the middle once it goes below the level of the outlet at the side.
A picture is below. The damp pattern shows build up towards the middle. We haven't had heavy rain, but I am pretty sure that if we did the water would pool substantially in the middle.
The head of the company is coming to visit, but I have the impression that they are unwilling to reprofile the roof so it falls to the side, and will claim that the installation is adequate.
I was wondering if people consider this to be an adequate job.
Thanks.


If you have it in writing, don't pay until that spec is met.

Thanks. Given two attempts so far, I am not sure they are capable of meeting the spec, and they are already saying that the spec is wrong, and shouldn't have been agreed...

If you've got it in writing, you have them over a barrel.  If they can't fix it, tell them to hire a roofer who can.

The company redid the roof for the second time, and finally did a proper job. It still does not fully meet the spec (e.g. it drains into a hopper rather than use pre-existing pipe, which I am not happy about for aesthetic, rather than functional reasons), but it now functions as a flat roof, and drains properly, and I do not want to get into legal wrangling. I won't use them again as there is a poor join up between the people who do the quotes, and the people who actually do the job.
